# Why does Adsense show a yellow box on my Wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, adsense

I have just added the AdSense code in my wordpress blog: http://surlaroute.com.mx/blog/ using the text widget but nothing is displaying. At first a yellow box was displayed. Nevertheless, by mega-googling, i have just found that the code generated by adSense, does not deliver the complete URL of the `adsbygoogle.js`. Check the URL of the `adsbygoogle.js`

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- SurLaRouteSinglePost -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:200px;height:200px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-A_NUMBER"
     data-ad-slot="ANOTHER NUMBER"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

So you can see that the "**http:**" is missing. Ok, i fixed it but i still can't see the adds :(  I would really appreciate if someone help me with this issue.

**Notes**:
The ads should appear on the left sidebar just below the title "Useful links".
My adsense account is properly working.

Hey, actually, stackoverflow detected that the link is wrong...

Comment: The "http:" is not missing - it is done that way so that whether your page is HTTPS (uses SSL) or is HTTP it will work using whatever transport layer got the user to the page.

Answer (score 6):

If you have created an Adsense account recently, like the day you posted this question, just add the code that they gave you (DO NOT CHANGE ANY PART OF THE CODE), and wait until it appears, it's gonna be with a yellow background until Google review your website and see that your website is good to display their ads.

Comment: I have the same issue, and I wondered if that might be the problem.  It's too bad the Adsense console doesn't show the status as "Pending" or something if this is the situation, instead of just "New".  How long does the review usually take?  Thx

Comment: If it's a recent account most likely it's the same issue @metaforge . Yes I agree that would be a better way so a person can tell or be aware of what's going on. It might take up to 24h.